# How to get payload from REST API Journey into Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

The REST payload for a journey has the `ContactKey` and `EventDefinitionKey` but also a `event_id`, `firstname` and other fields (defined in the journey data extension). The journey allows for re-entry anytime and each request has a UUID `event_id`. How do I dynamically inject the `event_id` into the email? The ContactKey can be in the Journey Data Extension multiple times, so I need the unique `event_id`.

Payload to Journey:

```
{
    "ContactKey": "1234",
    "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-UUID",
    "data": {
        "event_id": "UUID",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe"
    }
}
```

I tried (Email AMP Script):

```
set @event_id = AttributeValue("event_id")
```

since this is evaluated within the send context but it returns the empty string.

EDIT: I resolved the problem; updating the amp script in the email requires a new version of the journey to be activated. It sends a cached version apparently. Leaving post for visibility.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5

Comment: @EazyE thanks; so i can click edit and done to update the existing version and retain current version tracking or create a new version for new tracking. Appreciate it!